# 'Stable marriage', and an n factorial solution

Tags: algorithm, factorial

The [Stable marriage problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) is a pretty famous problem and most of you probably know about the [solution](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~evs/intro/stable/writeup.html) presented by Gale Shapley.

Based on the preference lists of males and females, there could be n! ([n-factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)) solutions to the problem (where n is the total number of males / females, males and females are equal in number and both have mentioned the preferences for all the given males/females)

What I want to know is:
Is there any way to modify the algorithm so that I can get all the solutions? I tried permutation, I thought changing the order of the man preference list might change the results, it really does but it I can see some same results.

Comment: There are n males and n females.  Every permutation p of n elements is a new unique matching - male p[0] goes to female 1, male p[1] goes to female 2, etc.  All you need to do is check whether it is a stable match

Comment: Fix the order of one gender, and then generate all permutations of the other gender, ignoring preference. Corresponding male/female indices create a pair. Each permutation is a possible solution for which you can calculate the (in)stability.

Comment: There may be many fewer than n! stable matchings. Is it important that the running time be proportional to the number of matchings?

Comment: let's assume there are 2 matrices of 3 by 3, one for females preference and the other for males. There will be 6 solutions to this problem since there are total 3 pairs to be made. @DavidEisenstat there isn't any issue of running time.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo Can you please share your findings ? I am interested in this problem too and looking for a solution. Thank you.

Comment: @purrogrammer how can I help you man?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo Could you find a solution to get all the matches ?

Comment: yes, I found a code that gives you stable matches.